# localhost not showing anything

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Apache is running in Xampp localhost not showing anything. Please help me. I want to run my php codes. In xampp apache & mysql is running. but in browser localhost & localhost/phpmyadmin saying that "Can't reach this page".
I'm new here that's why I can't post images here. please help me.

Comment: can you say what is your operating system?

Comment: I'm using Win 10 x64

Comment: check `netstat -an` in command line check the port and host

Comment: Buddy I'm sorry to say,I'm never seen even interface of it! any way pleas check your htdocs folder and find are there folder call phpmyadmin,  go to the folder call apache2/sites-enabled/ and check are there directory phpmyadmin included

Comment: You need to check if http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost is working or not. If everything is ok, you will see a xampp page. If not then other program may be using port required by apache.

Comment: @nizar 
in htdocs there is no folder called phpmyadmin. and there is no folder called apache2. what should i do now ??

Comment: @ RN Kushwaha ............... localhost is not working but apache & mysql service is started. :(

Comment: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf go to here and give me screen shot of it

Comment: @nizar...........there is no folder as you said in my C: drive & how can I send the SS to you?

Answer (score 0):

Backup your project folder and Try reinstalling the XAMPP as a last resort . After reinstalling check the status of Apache and Mysql and copy only the project file to the htdocs folder.